# Output error 0 in a basic c program in finding repititions

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a C program to print the number of repetitions for a given number in an array. what ever value I give as the input , the function returns the value only 0 to me.. what might be the error..the code is attached

```
#include<Stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int occurence(int n, int arr[], int x);

void main()
{
    int x,arr[100],n,i;
    clrscr();
    printf("\nEnter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter the elements:");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\nEnter the element to be searched for repetitions: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("%d",occurence(n,arr,x));
    getch();
}

int occurence(int n,int arr[100], int x)
{
    int i,rep=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(x == arr[i])
        {
            rep++;
        }
}

return rep;wenter code here
}
```

Comment: Stdio with capital S?

Comment: Please could you do something with the indentation?

Comment: If you want anyone to look at this, first format it properly.  Hint:  Intent your code.

Comment: `scanf("%d",arr[i]);` ==> `scanf("%d", &arr[i]);` Please enable compiler warnings - no need to have asked the question.

Comment: At least the compiler can read this code. If you instruct it to issue warnings, you will find several things, the most important one being the wrong argument to `scanf`. (You should also enforce that `n` isn't greater then 100.)

Comment: After adding that & to `scanf("%d",arr[i]);` your code seems to be working. The 0 return value you got is UB - on my machine the execution just stopped

Answer (score 0):

Problem is on the line 13 it is supposed to be scanf("%d",&arr[i]);